# Grouping using the same value twice

Tags: powerbi, grouping

I have the below regions

California
North Central
Northeast
South Central
South East
Southwest
West

Basically, I want to have all the below plus Non-California (with all except California) in the same field is it possible with Groups

can I use the same field twice? Is it better to use DAX?

How can I do this?

Example

California
North Central
Northeast
South Central
South East
Southwest
West
Non-California

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What language are we using here?

Comment: Also do North Central, Northeast, etc refer to regions of California or the USA as a whole?

Comment: believe DAX is the language used in microsoft power bi @ofeliajesus please add power bi tag if this is what the question pertains to

Comment: Is Power BI I want to use Data Groups in columns or DAX if I can't do this with Data Groups

Comment: Hi @ofeliajesus  Data Groups in Power BI??  Maybe You meant "Calculation Groups" ?

Comment: @JamesRisner DAX is a short for Data Analytics Expressions. It is a powerful analytics language used by power bi, power pivot, and SSAS tabular engines to create powerful and complex queries and calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to duplicate the rows that related to the Non-California regions and assign them to a region called Non-California.

I would try first to do that in the source data query, but since I don't know what that is, I will outline also how to do it with Power Query.

In Power Query, create QueryA which is a reference to the existing query with the rows that need duplicating. Create a filter for Region <> California. Replace values in Region with Non-California.

Create another QueryB which is also a reference to the original query. Append Query A to Query B.

Uncheck the load data options on the original query and QueryA. Load QueryB only.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works I tested it with
two tables and after I did a union to the both

Data1 =
VAR _Non_California =
SUMMARIZE (
FILTER ( 'Data', 'Data'[Region] <> "California" ),
Data[Account Name], Data[Amount Currency]
"Region", "Non-California",
"Amount", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Amount] ))

```
)
```

RETURN
_Non_California

Data_all = Union(
SELECTCOLUMNS(data,"Account Name", Data[Account Name],"Amount", Data[Amount],"Amount Currency", Data[Amount Currency],"Region", Data[Region]),
SELECTCOLUMNS(data1,"Account Name", Data1[Account Name],"Amount", Data1[Amount],"Amount Currency", Data1[Amount Currency],"Region", Data1[Region])
)

Thank you